# Upgrading Spark 1.3 to Spark 1.4 - Hive Context Issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to upgrade a Java application using Spark 1.3 to using Spark 1.4.  We previously allowed for multiple Hive databases/contexts by having the query be something like:

```
select * from default.table_name
```

But now, when I execute such a query from Spark SQL, I get an error saying that

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table default.table_name; line 1 pos 215
```

Removing the database name works, so if I query for

```
select * from table_name
```

in my Java application I have no issues, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what changed between Spark 1.3 and 1.4 to cause this issue, and what the fix is to use different contexts.  I'm not seeing anything in the `SQLContext` or `HiveContext` API (although I'm admittedly still looking), and I also verified by running Hive that the table exists and that the query above with the database name works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the placement of the backticks - the original query (that works in Spark 1.3) is as such:

```
select * from `default.table_name`
```

Which worked in Spark 1.3 and is failing in Spark 1.4.  I changed the backticks to be the following:

```
select * from `default`.`table_name`
```

And the query is now working successfully in Spark 1.4.